# Is there a way to decrypt a password using Argon2i Encryption?

Tags: passwords, salt, password-encryption, nextcloud, saltedhash

So I have a password that my password manager overwrote, and I self host the server (NextCloud) and I would like to know if it is possible to revert the hashed password with the salt key I have, I heard NextCloud uses Argon2i when using PHP 7.0 and later (and I'm running PHP 7.0 or later) so is it possible to revert my password back to it's original state and put it back into the password manager (Sorry I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to dehashing/decrypting passwords because I've never needed to dehash/decrypt my passwords before)

Edit: If I were to provide my argon'd password, could someone crack it or better yet tell me how to crack it, based on the mysql database it seems to have the parameters used to make the password by argon (probably to de-argon it to check if the password is actually correct)

Comment: It's not encryption. https://www.techsolvency.com/passwords/dehashing-reversing-decrypting/

Comment: So there is no way to "reverse" the hashing? even with a key?

Comment: @JordanPlayz158 correct, that's why it's called hashing, not encrypting.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

This is a very specific solution but in the event that you are using nextcloud and you have access to the account when losing your password, just download all the files, make a new account and upload them to that account and delete the old account